# Get text content of a class but from an object, not from the dom itself

Tags: jquery

Usually when I want to get the text content of a class i just use a selector that will scan the entire dom.

Problem is that in my context I don't want it to scan the entire dom but a specific portion of html that I have cached in a variable with a jquery selector:

```
let searchHtml = $( "#search-results > p" )
```

Now, from lodash I need to iterate each of the elements in searchHtml and extract text of those with a class "link-title":

```
 _.each( searchHtml, function( value, key ) {
            const linkTitle = $( value[".link-title"] ).text() // HERE
}
```

how to properly format this code so linkTitle in the loop will correctly grab text from element with class "link-title" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) no need of `lodash`. Here [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) is used to target descendants `link-title` element after that `.text()` can be used

```
let searchHtml = $( "#search-results > p" )
searchHtml.find(".link-title").each(function(index, element){
     const linkTitle = $(element).text(); //Native code "element.textContent;"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `find()` to get all the elements with a class of `.link-title`, use jquery `each()` to loop through them, use a array to save the text for each item found

```
searchHtml.find(".link-title").each(function(){
  linkTitle.push($(this).text());
  console.log($(this).text());
})
```